# Python just executed 1 line

Tags: python, loops, sha256

hi I'm new to python code. I tried to make a program to generate a private key from hex.
I make a hex list as .txt like
80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

and importing into code

when I try to execute the file only the first line is executed
whereas in the txt file there are 5 lines

is there a way for all lists to be executed?
where is my code error?

```
output_file = open("output.txt", "w")

# Step 2: let's add 80 in front of it
with open("generate.txt", "r") as extended_key:
    data = extended_key.readline().replace("\n", "")


# Step 3: first SHA-256
first_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(data)).hexdigest()
# Step 4: second SHA-256
second_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(first_sha256)).hexdigest()
# Step 5-6: add checksum to end of extended key
final_key = data+second_sha256[:8]
# Step 7: finally the Wallet Import Format is the base 58 encode of final_key
WIF = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(final_key))

output_file.write (WIF)
```

Comment: `.readline()` only reads the first line of the file.  Use `.read()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use readlines() to obtain a list containing all the lines and then loop over this list.

Comment: Please consider rating the answers.

Comment: As proposed data = extended_key.readlines(). This will give you a list containing all the lines in your file without the \n. Then you can iterate over the list and do all your digest. You have the choice to put it in a new list or the same and then write the full list using output_file.writelines(data)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the above segment with this. fileOb.read() reads the whole content whereas fileOb.readline() reads only one line.

```
# Step 2: let's add 80 in front of it
with open("generate.txt", "r") as extended_key:
    data = extended_key.read().replace("\n", " ") #to read all the lines and replace the newline characters by spaces
```

Comment: I have tried it but it produces long words without spaces

Comment: it should work.use debugger to check where the variables show unexpected behavior.

Comment: heres the respons 800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005

Comment: so you want newline been replaced by spaces " " ?